# Fallo al capturar una imagen desde una función vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Tengo la siguiente función con la que intento hacer una captura del Form1 y mostrarla en un PictureBox, antes cierro la aplicación de capturar la pantalla por si estuviese abierta:

```
Public Sub Captura_pantalla(form As Form1)

        'CAPTURAR, GUARDAR Y MOSTRAR LA IMAGEN EN EL PICTUREBOX
        'PRIMERO CERRAMOS SI ESTÁ ABIERTO EL PICPICK

        Dim procesos As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("picpick")

        If procesos.Length > 0 Then

            For i = procesos.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1

                procesos(i).Kill()

            Next

            MessageBox.Show("PICPICK CERRADO.", " CERRANDO PROCESO. ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End If

        Thread.Sleep(300)

        ' CAPTURAR LA VENTANA DE LA APLICACIÓN

        Dim png As New Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height)

        form.DrawToBitmap(png, New Rectangle(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height))

        ' MOSTRAR LA IMAGEN EN EL PICTUREBOX

        form.PictureBox1.Image = png

        ' GUARDAR LA IMAGEN COMO PNG

        png.Save("D:\Documentos\Escaneados\Informe_medico_infarto_2019\Tension\tension.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

    End Sub
```

En la línea :"Dim png As New Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height)" me da el error de que "'New' no se puede usar en una interfaz."
¿Podéis ayudarme con el problema? Gracias y Felices Fiestas.